# Can't reach local DynamoDB from Lambda in AWS SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I have a simple AWS SAM setup with a Go lambda function. It's using https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2 for dealing with DynamoDB, the endpoint is set via environment variables from the template. (Here: https://github.com/abtercms/abtercms2/blob/main/template.yaml)

My problem is that I can't get my lambda to return anything from DynamoDB, as a matter of fact I don't think it can reach it.

```
{
    "level":"error",
    "status":500,
    "error":"failed to fetch item (status 404), err: operation error DynamoDB: GetItem, exceeded maximum number of attempts, 3, https response error StatusCode: 0, RequestID: , request send failed, Post \"http://127.0.0.1:8000/\": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8000: connect: connection refused",
    "path":"GET /websites/abc",
    "time":1658243299,
    "message":"..."}
```

I'm able to reach the local DynamoDB just fine from the host machine.

Results were the same both for running DynamoDB in docker compose and via the .jar file, so the problem is not there as far as I can tell.

Also feel free to check out the whole project, I'm just running `make sam-local` and `make curl-get-website-abc` above. The code is here: https://github.com/abtercms/abtercms2.

Comment: The error messages seems to indicate that you are connecting to localhost. Obviously that endpoint is only relevant when testing against DynamoDB Local and shouldn't be in place when actually running in AWS Lambda.

Comment: @jarmod that is the point. I am running dynamodb local and want to connect to it from my lambda also running locally.